# Why are events not firing after the second render in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am creating an app in Backbone.js which has a parent and multiple child views. The child views contain links which they listen to and perform a function.

The parent stores a list of all of the children views. In the render function, after it is done computing its own html, it does the following:

```
$(this.el).html(html);
for (var i = 0; i < this.views.length; i++){
    $('.children', this.el).append(this.views[i].render().el);
}
```

ANSWER: The problem was that I was creating the link during the render. I.e. on the first render (which was called from the init) the event successfully binded to the link. However, since all following calls of render recreate the whole element, the new link did not have the handler bound to it. This was solved via @Tom Tu solution of adding `this.delegateEvents()` to the render

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are probably using jquery `remove` function somewhere to remove the subviews from the view  - it automatically removes all the events bound to the element (this.el) - set in the `events` object. You can either use `this.delegateEvents()` method in render of the subviews after you render template to rebind the event delegates set in `events` object or use jquery `detach` method instead to remove elements from DOM without removing event bindings ([link](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)). The `delegateEvents` method is quite costly and thus i'd recommend the `detach` method for removing elements that you want to reuse if you are rendering long lists of subviews - irrelevant if it's just a couple of views.

Other possibility is that you've set the `events` object wrong - hard to tell from the amount of code provided, but i bet on the first one.

Comment: added a bit more details, hope it helps

Comment: that is a really good thought, but I added the remove code above. Also, the events cant be set wrong, or it wouldnt fire in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

A really common challenge. For future finders of this question, here's a great article about view rendering:

> You just need to make sure that delegateEvents is called to rebind the events on your subviews any time .html() runs. And since Backbone’s setElement calls delegateEvents already, a quick solution could look like this...

http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for. Thanks!