# Backbone.View event only fires once

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

the jumpToWave event gets only fired once, I dont understand why.

This is my view:

```
var WaveModalView = Backbone.View.extend({

template:_.template($('#tpl-wave-modal').html()),

events: {
    'hidden': 'remove',
    'click .jumpToWaveBtn':'jumpToWave'
},
    jumpToWave:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("JMP")
        var marker = this.model.collection.markers[this.model.id];
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        bounceMarker(marker,1750);
    },
render:function () {
    var model = this.model;
    var that  = this;
    $(this.el).html(this.template(model.toJSON()));

    if(model.get('waveReviews').length > 0){
        var reviewList = new WaveReviewList({model: model});
        $('#waveReviews' + model.id).html(reviewList.render().el);
    }

    this.$("#waveSync" + model.id).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(window.me){
            requestSyncWave(model.id,function(data){
               window.me.fetch();
            });
        }
    });

    this.$("#waveEdit" + model.id).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.waveUnderEdit = model;
        $(that.el).children(":first").modal('hide');
        openWaveEditModal(model);

    });

    return this;
}

});
```

This is the relevant button in the template:

```
<button class="btn btn-info jumpToWaveBtn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Auf Karte
            anzeigen</button>
```

I have multiple modals by the time I click the button. The event gets fired for every modal just once, after that "JMP" does not get logged anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see your code calling `render` on the `WaveModalView`, but I suspect the problem is that you do call `render()` from somewhere else, which, in turn, calls `$(this.el).html(...)`, which replaces the content of the view's element, and the newly inserted content has no events bound to its elements.

If this is indeed the problem, you can solve it by adding `this.delegateEvents()` at the end of your `render()` function.

For instance, check this question and the answers: [Why are events not firing after the second render in Backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307911/why-are-events-not-firing-after-the-second-render-in-backbone-js)

Comment: that did it, thank you. ciould you elaborate in delegateEvents?

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation on `delegateEvents()`? http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents